# node-sqlite3 Serialization fails : SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: foreign key constraint failed

Tags: sql, database, node.js, sqlite

In Express.js I am trying to do the following using the serialization of two queries where the second one depends on the first one:

1. I am trying to get an entryID using the first query
2. I use that entryID for the second query

As far as I understand, the second query is called before the first one completes. Also the "console.log("My entry: "+data.entryID);" returns the right entryID. Below I have shown the code I am using as well as the error I get. Any help would be appreciated.

```
db.serialize(function(){

    db.get("Select entryID from entry where pID=$pID",{$pID:participName},function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        foundID=data.entryID;
        console.log("My entry: "+data.entryID);
        });

        db.run("insert into observation(entryID, objID, data) values($entryID,1,$intro_counter)", {$entryID:foundID, $intro_counter:intro_counter});

});


 events.js:71
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
 Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: foreign key constraint failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `db.get` itself might be serialized, but the callback you give to `db.get` is still called asynchronously.

To solve this, move the `db.run` call into the callback.